# execute crontab twice daily at 00h and 13:30

Tags: cron

i want to execute a script twice daily at 00:00 and 13:30 so i write :

```
0,30 0,13 * * *
```

it seems wrong for me, because like this, the script will fire at 00:00 , 00:30 , 13:00 and 13:30. Any idea ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can't do what you want in one entry, since the two minute definitions will apply for both hour definitions (as you've identified).

The solution is (unfortunately) use two cron entries. One for 00:00 and one for 13:30.

An alternative is *perhaps* to execute one script at 00:00. That script would execute your original script, then wait 13.5 hours and then execute that script again. It would be easy to do via a simple sleep command, but I think it's *unintuitive*, and I'm not sure how `cron` manages such long running processes (what happens if you edit the `crontab` - does it kill a spawned job etc.)

Comment: I thought like you at first , but i said it's stupid to write two cron entries

Comment: It might be stupid, but it might be a) maintainable b) unavoidable

Comment: @wassim: cron is intended for nice repetitive intervals, not arbitrary times during a day. use two cron entries and move on.

Comment: @Ankush can you specify what that would look like please?

Comment: The best way with only one cronjob is to check minutes (or complete hour and minutes) within your script. so you will execute the real job only when conditions you are looking for are ok. There is no solution else I see currently.

Answer (score 154):

Try this-:  `00 01,13 * * *`

it will run at 1 A.M and 1 P.M

Comment: Which is not what the OP wants, surely - 'execute crontab twice daily at 00h and 13:30'. It's the difference in mins and hours that causes the issue

Comment: I actually think this is a nice workaround. changing specified time by <60 minutes is tolerable for a lot of cron use cases, imo

Answer (score 29):

You CAN NOT do that with cron on a single line.
You have to create 2 separate lines like so:

```
# Will run "YourCommand" at 00:00 every day of every months
#Min   Hours   D of the M       Month   D of the Week   Command
0      0       *                *       *               YourCommand

# Will run "YourCommand" at 13:30 every day of every months
30     13      *                *       *               YourCommand
```

Or, as a single line, you can run a command every x hours, like so:

```
# Will run "YourCommand" every 12 hours
0   */12   *   *   *   YourCommand
```

or

```
# Will run "YourCommand" at 1am and 1pm every day
0   1,13   *   *   *   YourCommand arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Try this out: 0 6,18 * * *
```

it will run at minute 0 past hour 6 and 18

Or you can try it out on [cronguru](https://crontab.guru/#0_6,18_*_*_*)

Comment: This is only correct answer

Answer (score 8):

try ...

```
00,30 00,13 * * * [ `date +%H%M` == 1330 ] || [ `date +%H%M` == 0000 ] && logger "its time"
```

Comment: too much complicated, previous answer is simpler

Comment: @Mehdi try implementing different minutes with previous answers

Comment: Check Ankush's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
0 1,13 * * *
```

What the above code means:

> Cron will run at minute 0 past hour 1 and 13

Sharing a screenshot from crontab.guru

[image: crontab-guru]

Answer (score 1):

30      0,13     *       *       *     somecommand.sh

This is just purely an example, but you will see that this is a cron entry that will run at 0:30AM and then 1:30PM (13 is 1 in military time). Just comma separate the hours, or comma separate whatever section of the cron.

Comment: Plus one for "military time", did not knew that name for 24hrs format.

Comment: OP says ,"i want to execute a script twice daily at 00:00 and 13:30". This answer does not satisfy 00:00.

Comment: LOL to 13 is 1 in military time. I mean yeah, that explains our world.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

0 10 9/**12** ? * *

At second :00, at minute :10, **every 12 hours** starting at 09am, of every day

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Only if you have the same minutes for each schedule. This will run your job twice a day at 1:00 & 13:00

```
0 1,13 * * *
```

You can try quickly more variations here: https://crontab.guru/