# Run CRON job everyday at specific time

Tags: cron, cpanel

Right now i am running my cron job everyday at 3.00PM

```
0    15    *    *    *
```

But I want to run my cron job twice in a day. 10.30AM and 2.30PM

```
0    30 10    *    *    *
```

I believe this command will run at 10.30AM. How should i run it in 2.30PM?

Comment: please read this  question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993556/execute-crontab-twice-daily-at-00h-and-1330

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Cron** utility is an effective way to schedule a routine background job at a specific time and/or day on an on-going basis.

**Linux Crontab Format**

> MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD

[image]

**Example**::*Scheduling a Job For a Specific Time*

The basic usage of cron is to execute a job in a specific time as shown below. This will execute the Full backup shell script (full-backup) on 10th June 08:30 AM.

> Please note that the time field uses 24 hours format. So, for 8 AM use
>   8, and for 8 PM use 20.

```
30 08 10 06 * /home/yourname/full-backup
```

- 30 – 30th Minute
- 08 – 08 AM
- 10 – 10th Day
- 06 – 6th Month (June)
- *– Every day of the week

In your case, for `2.30PM`,

```
30 14 * * * YOURCMD
```

1. 30 – 30th Minute
2. 14 – 2PM
3. *– Every day
4. *– Every month
5. *– Every day of the week

To know more about cron, visit this [website](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm).

Comment: wait but this is 1 time only right? isn't OP asking about 2 times

Answer (score 60):

From cron manual http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html:

> Lists are allowed.  A list is a set of numbers (or ranges) separated
>   by commas.  Examples: "1,2,5,9", "0-4,8-12".

So in this case it would be:

`30 10,14 * * *`

Comment: This is the most effective solution. Following web site is good for verbally understanding the cron schedules. https://crontab.guru

Answer (score 11):

you can write multiple lines in case of different minutes, for example you want to run at 10:01 AM and 2:30 PM

```
1 10 * * * php -f /var/www/package/index.php controller function

30 14 * * * php -f /var/www/package/index.php controller function
```

but the following is the best solution for running cron multiple times in a day as minutes are same, you can mention hours like `10,30` .

```
30 10,14 * * * php -f /var/www/package/index.php controller function
```