# how to run a unix script only during the night?

Tags: unix

I want to execute a script that takes 5 days to be finished but I want to run it only between 1 am and 9 am which will take 15 days to be finished. How to do it please ?

thank you

Comment: If the script contains a short-running loop (less than an hour), I'd put a delay on 8 AM to sleep until 1 AM. A more reliable solution is to refractor it to save current progress, exit at 9 AM, then tell cron to launch it everyday at 1 AM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574603/run-cron-job-everyday-at-specific-time

Comment: You can pause the process.