# Using linux' at command - scheduling daily / weekly possible?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, at-job

I recently came across the at command on the command line, but I am wondering whether I can write a bash script that somehow enables me to tell the at command to run at 8 pm every day, or every monday, every week etc. basically at regular intervals. How is this possible?

Comment: Check about `crontab` for this than `at`

Comment: Is there a possibility to do it with at though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execute crontab twice daily at 00h and 13:30](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993556/execute-crontab-twice-daily-at-00h-and-1330)

Comment: Inian is correct. at is a utility to schedule jobs 'later', for one-off things. cron is a utility to schedule repeating jobs.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder you could even do it using `at` by rescheduling your own job again at the end of your job. Although `cron` is the goto option for such a scenario

Comment: @ritesht93 ok fair enough! thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`at` is the wrong tool for this job.

You're looking for [`cron`](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/).

8 pm every day would be :

```
0 20 * * * /bin/execute/this/script.sh
```

8 pm every monday would be :

```
0 20 * * 1 /bin/execute/this/script.sh
```