# Cron 2 specific hour

Tags: cron

I want to programme a cron for 2 specifics hours : 14h15 and 22h15. How can I do that ?

Because I want to mix this 2 crons :

> 15 14 * * *
>
> 15 22 * * *

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574603/run-cron-job-everyday-at-specific-time/35575322#35575322 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993556/execute-crontab-twice-daily-at-00h-and-1330

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it: `15 14,22 * * *`.

There are a number of sites where you can test cron expressions. Here is one:
https://crontab.guru/#15_14,22_*_*_*